# dynamically apply timezone offset to a highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have a chart which ultimately I'd like to apply timezone offsets to from a dropdown list of timezones. The incoming times from json will all be UTC.

Is there a way to let highcharts handle the offset with the global timezoneOffset property, something along the lines of this when a button is clicked or dropdown selected:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global : {
    timezoneOffset : 300
  }
});
```

Maybe I also need to redraw the chart after doing this?

Example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/oqOAmUnH2LZzAX3a7vpV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`global.timezoneOffset`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.timezoneOffset) option is deprecated so I suggest using [`time.timezoneOffset`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezoneOffset) instead for a chart. With the chart-sentric option you can do a normal chart update to set a new `timezoneOffset`.

For example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pckry9j4/)):

```
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  time: {
    timezoneOffset: -120
  }
  // ...
});
```

And upon doing a dropdown selection:

```
chart.update({
  time: {
    timezoneOffset: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately im stuck with a highcharts version prior to 6.0.5 so I cannot use this option, can this still be achieved with the global option?

Comment: @mao this test does appear to do the same, for older versions: [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pckry9j4/1/). It uses `chart.redraw()`, but will also affect other charts when they eventually redraw, so it might have some side-effects if you are not careful.